# images are not displayed properly in smaller screens

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, mask, responsive-images

i am trying to create a responsive web site but i am stuck in one place that the images with a background-imaged mask are not functioning properly. It works fine with larger screens but in medium and small screens my headline and some of the images are not seen with the "masked" background image. So could you tell me where i am making the mistake? Is it coding or the method that i am doing wrong?

The pictures that how display the screen are at the bottom of this page.You can see in large screen there is no problem but in other screens you cant see the headline and only half of the images are shown and the background doesnt stretch to cover all images and headline!!!

[enter link description here](http://www.avrupahayalleri.com/) This is the website.You can see better what the problem is.

```js
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <!--Menü scroll change color-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll > 10) {
       $(".navbar").css("background", "black");
   }

   else{
       $(".navbar").css("background", "transparent");
   }
  })
})
    </script>
    <!--Menü scroll change color-->
```

```css
html,
body,
header,
#intro {
    height: 100%;
    
}

#intro {
    background:  url('../img/fft99_mf5629880.Jpeg') no-repeat center center fixed ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family:Arial;
}



.navbar-brand{
    font-family:      Gabriola;
    font-size:35px;
padding-top:10px;    
    
}

.navbar-nav li a  {
  color:white !important;
  font-family:   'Kristen ITC';
}

.fixed-top .navbar-nav  li a:hover {
    color: red !important;
}

.fixed-top .navbar-nav  li  a:focus {
    color: red !important;
}




.fixed-top.scrolled {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}

 .fixed-top.scrolled .navbar-nav   li a  {
  color:red !important;
}


 .fixed-top.scrolled .navbar-nav   li a:hover {
    color: red !important;
} 




 .float{
 position:fixed;
 width:60px;
 height:60px;
 bottom:40px;
 right:40px;
 background-color:#25d366;
 color:#FFF;
 border-radius:50px;
 text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  z-index:100;
}

.my-float{
 margin-top:16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Avrupa Hayalleri - Avrupa'yı Görme Hayalleriniz Gerçek Olsun</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ihover.css" >


</head>

<body>

    


    <!--Main Navigation-->
<header>
    
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  fixed-top  ">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Navbar brand -->
            <a class="navbar-brand red-text" href="#">BATU PARFÜM</a>

            <!-- Collapse button -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

            <!-- Collapsible content -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                <!-- Links -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Anasayfa <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bayan Parfüm</a>
                    </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Erkek Parfüm</a>
                    </li>
                         <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Unisex Parfüm</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">İletişim</a>
                    </li>


                </ul>
                <!-- Links -->

                <!-- Social Icon  -->
<ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons ">
    <li class="nav-item">
     <!--   <a class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-2x green-text "></i>0533 645 89 42</a>  -->
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=905382392398"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-2x green-text "> </i>0538 239 23 98 </a>
    </li>
</ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Collapsible content -->

        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--/.Navbar-->





    <!--Mask-->
<div  id="intro" class="view hm-black-strong  container-fluid ">
        
    <div class="container-fluid full-bg-img d-flex  align-items-center        justify-content-center   ">

        <div class="row container-fluid d-flex align-items-center     justify-content-center">

            <div class=" col-lg-8 col-md-8  col-sm-8  text-center ">
                 <hr class="hr-light   ">
                <!-- Heading -->
                <h1 class=" font-bold  mb-2       white-text">Kokunu Keşfet</h1>
                               <!-- Divider -->
                <hr class="hr-light pt-2   ">
                </div>
            

               <!--Grid row-->
    <div class="row col-lg-8 col-md-8  col-sm-8 container-fluid  text-center mt-5">

        <!-- Top to Bottom-->

        <!--Grid column-->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-8 mb-4   ">
            <h2 class="mb-4 font-weight-bold  white-text ">Unisex Parfüm</h2>
            <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight z-depth-1-half">
              <img src="img/perfume1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""  style="border:3px solid white; ">
              <div class="mask"></div>
          </div>         
        </div>
        <!--Grid column-->

        <!--Grid column-->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-8 mb-4">
                        <h2 class="mb-4 font-weight-bold  white-text">Bayan Parfüm</h2>
            <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight z-depth-1-half">
              <img src="img/f484004e6a670c4a5827535756317ba7a.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="" style="border:3px solid white; " >
              <div class="mask"></div>
          </div>

      
        </div>
        <!--Grid column-->

        <!--Grid column-->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-8 mb-4">
                        <h2 class="mb-4 font-weight-bold  white-text">Erkek Parfüm</h2>
            <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight z-depth-1-half">
              <img src="img/e9feb436d5ed39c882d93ac8fc207e82a.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="" style="border:3px solid white; ">
              <div class="mask"></div>
          </div>

            </div>
   
        
        
        <!--Grid column-->
        </div>
    
    <!--Grid row-->
             </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<!--/.Mask-->

</header>
<!--Main Navigation-->
</body>

</html>
```

[small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPxdH.png)

[medium screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9ZVu.png)

[large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqX7g.jpg)

Comment: I don't know what your problems are. Your site works fine in Chrome.

Comment: When you enter the website from mobile phone or ipad the headline and those 3 photos are not displayed properly when these photos are on top of another, it only works good in monitors or TV screens which are larger screens when the pictures are side by side..

Comment: How do you want them to look like?

Comment: You know in larger screens the headline is on the top row and then the images are in another row under headline and the images are side by side.
But in small and medium screens there are breakpoints that the headline is on the top and first image is under headline and other image is  under the first image  and this goes on and the background image stretches with them.. But if you opened the website in a phone you can see that , the headline is not displayed and you can see the half of the first image ,you can see the 2nd image full and you cannot see the 3rd image. So how can i fix this?

Comment: Your layout is not organized and hence it's hard for me to look at the page source. For example, you have so many nested `container-fluid`s. You only need to use one `container-fluid` where you want the container to be 100% width. Can you create a simple jsfiddle example that reproduces your error? That way at least we can help you figure things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use media queries for smaller screens. Try this css for mobile phones:

```
header{
    height: auto;
}
#intro{
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.full-bg-img{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply , although i didnt use this in my code it helped me to figure out that i should delete the  "html,body,header,"  from my css before "intro" ID... and because this makes the height %100 , in all of my pages there was huge unnecessary spaces that other elements of html were many beneath from the top of the page.